# google maps api request/googlemaps javascript

Tags: android, hybrid

I develop an application and i need to use somehow with google maps.
I tries both:
1.send request to "http://googleapis.com/maps/api........"(with key..).
2.javascript file of googlemaps.

and now I'm stuck with a big question that i cant find any complete answer(from what i understand).

**The question:**
I need from any user in my application to use the request something like 5-20 times a day(if the user will be very active). I read that there is a **limit** of **2500 requests a day**. This 2500 requests a day is **per user**?(sound the limit is only for not flooding google..am i right?). if it is 2500 requests for all users so I need much much much more then 2500.
there is a difference for google if I use option 1 or 2?(regular request/javascript file).

Thanks.

Comment: did you read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google's terms of use.  You should contact Google documentation or support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a displaying a Google map to a user, then there are no restrictions.

2500 requests/day is the limit for Google Directions API, which is used to create directions that you can get and display for your users (e.g. driving route from point A to point B).

However if the directions you are getting from the Directions API are repeated over and over, you could just save them as an XML file on your server (or the device) and re-use them, that way you can stay inside the 2500 limits.